# Find diameter from volume of sphere C++

Tags: c++

I have got a task to create a program that calculates the diameter of the sphere of volume 1234.67 cu meters.

I have Written the following code : -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    float vol, dm, h;
    vol = 1234.67;
    cout << "Calculating the diameter of sphere with volume 1234.67 cu meters" << endl;
    h = vol*(3/4)*(7/22);
    dm = 2 * cbrt(h);
    cout << "The diameter of sphere with volume 1234.67 cu meters is " << dm << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What's wrong with my program , it gives 0 as the output

```
Calculating the diameter of sphere with volume 1234.67 cu meters                                                                                                             
The diameter of sphere with volume 1234.67 cu meters is 0
```

Comment: Try searching for existing answers before asking a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
h = vol * (3 / 4) * (7 / 22);
```

should be

```
h = vol * (3.f / 4.f) * (7.f / 22.f);
```

as with `int` `3 / 4 == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `7/22` equals zero. Read about C's integer division [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c)

You need to use floating point division if you intend to use floating point precision.

Answer (score 0):

```
h = vol*(3/4)*(7/22);
dm = 2 * cbrt(h);
```

3,4,7,22, and 2 are integers. Change them to floats or doubles (3.0, or 3.f for example). This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You've used integer division everywhere, which disregards the floating part instead of rounding.

Use 3.f/4.f or 3.0/4.0 instead